# Chaining multiple GLES 2.0 programs

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to layer / chain multiple GLES 2.0 effects / programs. In my specific case the first pass renders a video frame, then a second pass renders some particles on top and finally I want to apply an animated zoom effect that transforms the whole composition. The way I go about chaining the shaders for now is by compiling / attaching / linking them individually and then calling glUseProgram() for each one in a row in my onDrawFrame() method.

```
    super.onDrawFrame(fbo); // this is where I call the previous glUseProgram() ...
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferName);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(getHandle("aPosition"));
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(getHandle("aPosition"), VERTICES_DATA_POS_SIZE, GL_FLOAT, false, VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(getHandle("aTextureCoord"));
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(getHandle("aTextureCoord"), VERTICES_DATA_UV_SIZE, GL_FLOAT, false, VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3); // texture #3 was just a guess but the previous ones appear to refer to stuff from the particles program, not the whole composition
    GLES20.glUniform2f(getHandle("zoomCenter"), .5f, .5f); // passing the variables to the shader, don't think there's a problem with that part, therefore not including their source
    GLES20.glUniform1f(getHandle("zoomFactor"), 2f);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(getHandle("aPosition"));
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(getHandle("aTextureCoord"));
```

This works well for the first two layers, I can draw my particles on the video as expected. The animated zoom shader by itself also works as expected, when I apply it to the uncomposed video frame.

When I run the code above however, I get something that kind of looks like it might be a zoom on the whole image, but then it gradually gets whiter with every frame and goes completely white after around a second.

I figured that might be because I called `GLES20.glBlendFunc` in the previous particles GL program, so some sort of additive blending would not be unexpected, but `GLES20.glDisable ( GLES20.GL_BLEND );` just gives me a black screen. Am I calling stuff in the wrong order or is my assumption nonsense that `GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3);` could be referring to the whole composition so far? Or maybe I just fundamentally misunderstand the way one would chain those shaders.

Comment: Do you clear the named framebuffer (`fbo`) and the default framebuffer (0) in every frame?

Comment: Your comment about "just a guess" for texture ID is worrying; it sort of implies that you are working alongside some other OpenGL ES library you can't see. OpenGL ES state is global to the context so it's possible you are changing some state that the other bits of rendering code are not expecting to change. In most (but not all) cases it's possible to "query" the current state using `glGet()` so you can backup/restore the parts you want to change.